# what are Google Chrome DevTool debugger blue marks?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints, javascript-debugger

in last 2-3 chrome versions I found out small blue sign when I set breakpoints, any one know what they are?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

ok, it soooooo cooool!
in the past I needed to debug lines with multiple functions calls and go inside a function, got outside, inside , outside ... ring a bell ?

whose blue "mini-breakpoints" let you just select the ones you want to debug. so no need to in/out all the time. see example:

[image]

hope it help.